# How to use class equation for determining the center of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

How to use class equation for determining the center of $S_4$

$$|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_x [G:C_G(x)]$$
So I guess I need to find $$|G|-\sum_x [G:C_G(x)]=|Z(G)|$$

Well $|S_4|=4!=24$

and $C_G(x)$ is the set of all group elements that commute with $x$. This seems like I would need to use brute force, and that would take a very long time, since each elements has numerous elements in it's centralizer. How do I work this out?

Comment: Do you know that two elements in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type? For instance $(12)(34)$ is conjugate to $(13)(24)$ but not $(123)$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Yep, I have proven this in the past. Am I meant to use Orbits?

Comment: No, but you can count the number of elements in each conjugacy class. For instance, the number of elements in the conjugacy class of $(12)(34)$ is precisely the number of ways you can partition $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into 2 pairs.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I have done this now and I have:

1-1-1-1 type has 1

1-1-2 type has 6

1-3 type has 8

4 type has 6

2-2 type has 3

For the total of 24. How do I solve the problem with this though?

Comment: Now note that something is in the center if and only if its conjugacy class is a singleton.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan In general? What is a singleton?

Comment: @Permute A singleton is a set with a single element, i.e., of the form $\{x\}$.  If the orbit of $x$ under conjugation is just $\{x\}$, then $gxg^{-1} = x$ for all $g$, so $gx = xg$.

Answer (score 0):

G= disjoint union of classes [x] under the conjugate relation. Any x aside from the identity element has only one of the forms: (12) with 6 elements , (123) with 8 elements , (1234) with 6 elements, (12)(34) with 3 elements elements. Thus the cardinalities of the nontrivial classes are 6,8,6,and 3. We are left with only one trivial class of one element and it is [e]={e}. Thus Z(G)={e}.

Comment: So I take it that $\sum_{x}[G:C_G(x)]$ is the sum of conjugacy classes?

I wasn't entirely sure how to read that one. It seems like the quotient of $G$ with the centrilizer.

Comment: @Permute The size of an orbit is the index of the stabilizer.  ([See here.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem))  In this case the action is conjugation, so the stabilizer is the centralizer.  The size of the orbit of $x$ is thus $[G: C_G(x)]$.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments,  the elements of $S_n$ of same cycle type are conjugate.   And conversely.

So, there's only one odd man out:  $e$.

There's more than one of each (non-trivial) cycle type.

We get immediately that the center is trivial. Actually for all $n\ge3$.  ($S_2$ is abelian of course. )

That's the class equation for $S_n,\,n\ge3$ is $$\underbrace {1}_{\text{center}}+\underbrace{\text{junk}}_{ \text{classes of size $\gt1$}}$$.

When you look at the class equation,  adding up the $1$'s gives the order of the center.